# Bad torrent experience: How can I punish a miner owner?

Tags: malware, torrent

I have downloaded a program from torrent tracker. After installation I've found that bitcoin miner has been installed on my PC as well. My electricity bills are huge now and I don't want to pay for it.

How can I punish owner of that miner? Can I tell police about the case or some other institution? And what is the probability that police will take this case?

Comment: While this is off-topic, the likelihood the police will take the case is very low, and you should probably write it off and consider the extra electric bills surrogate payment for the program you torrented instead of purchasing.

Comment: "I let someone unknown enter my house and he did drink all the beers !!! Now he's gone, what can I do so he pay the beers ?" (a little hyperbolic, but that's it)

Comment: ...and this is why you don't download pirated software off shady torrent sites! "If an attacker can run a program on your computer, it's not your computer anymore."

Answer (score 2):

First off, you shouldn't be using pirated software. I would suggest running an antivirus scan and see what it finds, and can remove.  If you can't get rid of the bitcoin miner, either with antivirus, manually deleting it, or another way, you will probably have to re-install your computer.  As other posters have commented, there is very low likelihood that the police would take the case.  It would be like someone going to the police saying the drug dealer cheated me (e.g. you would possibly be in trouble too).

Probably the best way to punish the miner owner is to clean up your computer, and not use torrent sites in the future.  Also encourage others not to use torrent sites.  People are usually in it for profit, so if they are giving you free software, what else are they giving you?  Probably malware to get access to your banking info, in this case a bitcoin miner, etc...  If enough people listen, and stop using torrent sites, then business will probably dry up for the crooks!